# Why does internet is not working and edge or chrome saying DNS-server issue whenever connecting to an OpenVPN server?

Tags: server, lubuntu, openvpn

whenever I am connecting to OpenVPN, not able to browse anything on chrome or edge, getting DNS-server issue.

Comment: What OS & release are you using?  Assuming it's modern Lubuntu, have you checked out the manual - https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/G/AdvancedNetworking.html  (which provides some clues for setting up VPNs)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1289297/edit) and add the following information. Which version of Ubuntu are you using? Are you using WSL? How are you conniving to VPN? Is it corporate, office server or a consumer VPN service, or your own server?